# excel custom function for a loop

Tags: loops, excel, vba

I'm a newbie to excel VB so I hope some one can help me with this:
I'm trying to calculate the row number of the first cell which doesn't have the value zero in a column(eg:if it's 0 0 0 1 should give me 4) but have a hard time in making it display on the worksheet,
Here is my code-

```
Function Module1(y As Integer)
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
Dim a As Integer
a = 0
Do While x < 100 Or a <> 0
    If Cells(x, y).Value = 1 Then
    a = x

x = x + 1
Loop
Cells(y, 101).Value = a
End Function
```

y is the column number I want to get this function and there are 100 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare a function 'Module1'. Not a good name for a function because 'Module1' used to be the name of the code container 'Module1'.

So:

press Alt+F11, right click on your Project, add a module (autonumbering gives your new module the name Module1, Module2 etc), type this code:

```
Public Function GetNonZeroRank(r As Range)
x = 1
Do While x <= r.Rows.Count And a = 0
    If r.Cells(x, 1).Value <> 0 Then
    a = x
End If
x = x + 1
Loop
GetNonZeroRank = a
End Function
```

You can use this function from cell A101: type in the formula:

```
=GetNonZeroRank(A1:A100)
```

Thats how to use (Public) Functions

Important: you can't change cell values from inside a function called from a sheet:

> Cells(y, 101).Value = a

you can do this inside a Sub method

Answer (score 0):

A few points, in addition to those made by the other responses:

- By your code it seems that you are looping over 100 **rows** and the
  result is displayed in row `x` (which is the first non zero row of
  column `y`) and column `101`. Is this what you really want?
- *Why a function and not a subroutine*?
  Unless you want to use it from the spreadsheet (in which case you can change only the content of the cell from which you call it, generally speaking), a function is not useful here. It would be useful if you would assign the return value of a function to another variable.
- *your code will crash if you go more than row `32,767`*, which is the biggest number an `Integer` can hold. I can see that you need your code to run until row 100, but I would suggest using `Long`, which
  is more robust and actually faster to evaluate.
- Your code exits the loop under the condition `a<>0` when a cell value equals one. In your description you state that you want to get the row number of the *first non-zero cell*, which, in general, it does not have to be the first non-zero cell that equals to 1. Which of the two do you actually want?
- Actually, there is a trick that avoids the loop altogether (see below).

  ```
   Sub test1()
      test 1
  End Sub

  ' Optional passes a default value to the argument. 
  ' If no value is given here,  then y = 1
  Sub test(Optional y As Long = 1) 
    Dim x As Long
    With Sheet1
      x = .Evaluate("MATCH(1,--(" & .Range(.Cells(1, y), .Cells(100, y)).Address & "<>0),0)")
        .Cells(101, y) = x
    End With
  End Sub
  ```

The above uses `EVALUATE` to parse an excel formula.

The idea is that

- The array part is (example for column `A`) `A1:A100<>0`, which is a binary
  array that looks like `{FALSE, FALSE, ..., TRUE, ...}`
- `--{FALSE, FALSE, ..., TRUE, ...}` Evaluates to `{0, 0, ..., 1, ...}`
- `MATCH(1,{0,0, ...,1, ...},0)` returns the position of the first `1` that is found
- I would also wrap this expression in an `IFERROR` statement to control what happens if all values are `0`.

We can actually test the excel version of this formula in a cell. It has to be array entered (confirmed with `Control + Shift + Enter`), which happens automatically when entered from `VBA`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I wouldn't discourage a function for this.  A function returns a value and a sub does not.  It's really not specific to in-cell formulas as it can be very helpful to utilize functions in other subs to modularize your design into reusable code and preventing duplicate less maintainable code.

Comment: @PortlandRunner I agree with the modularization argument and that the use of functions is not specific to in-cell formulas. My sense is that the modularization argument is not relevant in this particular context (using a sub does not make the design less modular), and if the OP does not intend to call this procedure from a cell, I think a sub is a more elegant choice. Also, the OP does not seem to return anything from the function on his original code, so I suspected that he might not be aware of `sub`s in the first place.